# How to make a module reload in python after the script is compiled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, reload

#### The basic idea involved:

I am trying to make an application where students can write code
related to a specific problem(say to check if the number is even) The
code given by the student is then checked by the application by
comparing the output given by the user's code with the correct output
given by the correct code which is already present in the application.

#### The basic version of the project I am working on:

An application in which you can write a python script (in tkinter text
box). The contents of the text box are first stored in a `test_it.py`
file. This file is then imported (on the click of a button) by the
application. The function present in `test_it.py` is then called to
get the output of the code(by the user).

#### The problem:

Since I am "importing" the contents of `test_it.py` , therefore,
during the runtime of the application the user  can test his script
only once. The reason is that python  will import the `test_it.py`
file only once. So even after saving the new script of the user in
test_it.py , it wont be available to the application.

#### The solution:

[Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module#:%7E:text=To%20use%20it%2C%20run%20reload,will%20reload%20the%20math%20module.) `test_it.py` every time when the button to test the script is clicked.

#### The actual problem:

While this works perfectly when I run the application from the script,
this method fails to work for the compiled/executable version(.exe) of the file (which is expected since during compilation all the imported modules would be
compiled too and so modifying them later will not work)

#### The question:

I want my `test_it.py` file to be reloaded even after  compiling the application.

---

If you would like to see the working version of the application to test it yourself. You will find it [here](https://github.com/JDeepD/Open-Palm).

Comment: You could launch the application using `-B` [command line flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id1) to prevent bytecode creation, if that is what you mean by 'compiled version of the file'

Comment: @MauriceMeyer By compiled , I mean making a `.exe` . Sorry for the confusion.  I dont know much terminology

Comment: You create .exe with pyinstaller?

Comment: @viilpe ya. Not exactly with pyinstaller, but [this](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) (which uses pyinstaller at its backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for the bundled application imports work the standard way. That means whenever an `import` is encountered, the interpreter will try to find the corresponding module. You can make your `test_it.py` module discoverable by appending the containing directory to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). The `import test_it` should be dynamic, e.g. inside a function, so that it won't be discovered by PyInstaller (so that PyInstaller won't make an attempt to bundle it with the application).

Consider the following example script, where the app data is stored inside a temporary directory which hosts the `test_it.py` module:

```py
import importlib
import os
import sys
import tempfile

def main():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        f_name = os.path.join(td, 'test_it.py')

        with open(f_name, 'w') as fh:  # write the code
            fh.write('foo = 1')

        sys.path.append(td)  # make available for import
        import test_it
        print(f'{test_it.foo=}')

        with open(f_name, 'w') as fh:  # update the code
            fh.write('foo = 2')

        importlib.reload(test_it)
        print(f'{test_it.foo=}')

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem summary:

A `test_it.py` program is running and has a predicate available, e.g. `is_odd()`.
Every few minutes, a newly written file containing a revised `is_odd()` predicate becomes available,
and test_it wishes to feed a test vector to revised predicate.

There are several straightforward solutions.

1. Don't load the predicate in the current process at all. Serialize the test vector, send it to a [newly forked child](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which computes and serializes results, and examine those results.
2. Typically [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is evil, but here you might want that, or exec.
3. Replace current process with a newly initialized interpreter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl
4. Go the memory leak route. Use a counter to assign each new file a unique module name, manipulate source file to match, and load *that*. As a bonus, this makes it easy to diff current results against previous results.
5. [Reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload): `from importlib import reload`

Comment: I have not tried them(except the 5th) but I have a question regarding the 1st one. When using `subprocess.Popen()` or equivalent, will the application run(after the application is made into .exe)  in a system which does not have python 3 installed ?

Comment: Wanting to run arbitrary *.py source code on a system which lacks a python interpreter is, ummm, an **unusual** design requirement. The .check_output() routine I cited is pretty simple -- it will fork + exec any program you wish, e.g. /usr/bin/date, and return what it sent to stdout. I had in mind that you might want to run a python interpreter which accepts some source code as input, given that you have a freshly received source file in hand. But I suppose you could arrange other interface if you really wanted to, such as requiring code submitter to compile to x86 on his end. numba.pydata.org

Answer (score 1):

The key is to check if program are running as exe and add exe path to the *sys.path*.

File *program.py*:

```
import time
import sys
import os
import msvcrt
import importlib

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # This is .exe so we change current working dir
    # to the exe file directory:
    app_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    print('    Add .exe path to sys.path: ' + app_path)
    sys.path.append(app_path)
    os.chdir(app_path)

test_it = importlib.import_module('test_it')

def main():
    global test_it
    try:
        print('    Start')
        while True:
            if not msvcrt.kbhit(): continue
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            if key in b'rR':
                print('    Reload module')
                del sys.modules['test_it']
                del test_it
                test_it = importlib.import_module('test_it')
            elif key in b'tT':
                print('    Run test')
                test_it.test_func()
            time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('    Exit')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

File *test_it.py*:

```
def test_func():
    print('Hi')
```

Create an .exe file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile  --clean program.py
```

Copy _text_it.py to the _dist_ folder and it's done.
Press *t* in program window to run `test_func`. Edit *test_it.py* then press *r* to reload module and press *t* again to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution is to use the [code module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html):

```
import code
# get source from file as a string
src_code = ''.join(open('test_it.py').readlines())
# compile the source
compiled_code = code.compile_command(source=src_code, symbol='exec')
# run the code
eval(compiled_code) # or exec(compiled_code)
```